# How detect touch on locked screen in android?

Tags: android, touch

If it is duplicate please inform and I will delete this post.

I have been looking for answers for several days and nothing I found is useful. If you have any links that might lead to a solution, please share them.

I stood in the application for a moment, where I have to read that the user clicked on the off screen (n times). This is needed to unlock the device.

Is it possible to read a touch event on the locked screen? Or maybe it should be done differently? It is certainly possible, because there are applications that offer such functionality.

Comment: Simply you can't, the hardware will release the touch events when the screen is locked, only if your app is system app, then and only then you can.

Comment: Do you know any resources about my problem, if it's a systemic one? I am able to change the application to the system application.

Comment: But there is apps with this feature without root access e.g. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appz.doubletap.lock.unlock&hl=pl&gl=US

Comment: as I saw in the comments: 
"This app is a wonderful app. I really love this app because I lost my power button in my phone. It is very useful for me to lock and unlock my phone without power button. I am giving only 4 stars because it is not showing the lock screen when I double tap to open the screen but it shows the desktop."
This means that the app doesn't lock the screen, it simply dims the screen to be black, but it's not locking the screen actually.

Comment: But this is enough for me. If I try set brightness to min screen still was visible

Comment: Create a fullscreen dialog that has a black background, run the dialog and make the brightness to the minimum, this will work